# Can't decode a JSON file from web in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, weather-api

I have some code below, which gets a response from a website fine, my code works until it gets to the decoding bit, but returns no objects.
This is my first attempt at JSON and web related data.

It works fine until:
Dim dict As Object
which returns nothing, I've tried several alternatives from the web, but am stumpt.

here is the URL of the website for the JSON:
https://www.metcheck.com/OTHER/json_data.asp?zipcode=wv12+4qz&locationID=60883&lat=52.6&lon=-2

Here is he URL that will show the JSON File:
http://ws1.metcheck.com/ENGINE/v9_0/json.asp?lat=52.6&lon=-2&lid=60883&Fc=No

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class Weather
    Private Sub Weather_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim uriString As String = "http://ws1.metcheck.com/ENGINE/v9_0/json.asp?lat=52.6&lon=-2&lid=60883&Fc=No"
    Dim uri As New Uri(uriString)

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.Method = "GET"

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()


    Dim read As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim raw As String = read.ReadToEnd

    Dim dict As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of List(Of Object))(raw)

    For Each item As Object In dict
        TextBox1.Text = item("temperature").ToString & vbCrLf
        TextBox1.Text = item("dewpoint").ToString & vbCrLf
        TextBox1.Text = item("rain").ToString & vbCrLf
    Next


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use .DeserializeObject instead and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with JavaScriptSerializer before, but this might be because you're trying deserialize to a List(of object) instead of a more specific type. If you add series of classes matching the structure of the JSON:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property metcheckData As Metcheckdata
    Public Property feedCreation As Date
    Public Property feedCreator As String
    Public Property feedModel As String
    Public Property feedModelRun As String
    Public Property feedModelRunInitialTime As Date
    Public Property feedResolution As String
End Class

Public Class Metcheckdata
    Public Property forecastLocation As Forecastlocation
End Class

Public Class Forecastlocation
    Public Property forecast As List(Of Forecast)
    Public Property continent As String
    Public Property country As String
    Public Property location As String
    Public Property latitude As Single
    Public Property longitude As Single
    Public Property timezone As Integer
End Class

Public Class Forecast
    Public Property temperature As String
    Public Property dewpoint As String
    Public Property rain As String
    Public Property freezinglevel As String
    Public Property uvIndex As String
    Public Property totalcloud As String
    Public Property lowcloud As String
    Public Property medcloud As String
    Public Property highcloud As String
    Public Property humidity As String
    Public Property windspeed As String
    Public Property meansealevelpressure As String
    Public Property windgustspeed As String
    Public Property winddirection As String
    Public Property windletter As String
    Public Property icon As String
    Public Property iconName As String
    Public Property chanceofrain As String
    Public Property chanceofsnow As String
    Public Property dayOfWeek As String
    Public Property weekday As String
    Public Property sunrise As String
    Public Property sunset As String
    Public Property dayOrNight As String
    Public Property utcTime As Date
End Class
```

And then try to deserialise as follows:

```
Dim dict As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Rootobject)(raw)
```

Does that work as expected?

Comment: There's no reason to deserializing to Object, since youv'e already specified the type: deserialize to `Dim dict As Rootobject = ...` (maybe using more meaningful names). Also, note that the OP is declaring its WebRequest/WebResponse the wrong way (probably `Option Strict` is off). It should be (minimum requirement) `Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri) Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)`. Then it will work, at least with a non-SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that you are trying to deserialize into a List but your JSON actually represents a single object containing a data property which then contains a list of objects. That is why you are getting this error. Json.Net can't deserialize a single object into a list. I think what you really want to do is define a container class

```
Public Class Metdata
    Public Property myDictionary As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
End Class
```

And then your sub will look like:

```
    Private Sub Weather_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim uriString As String = "http://ws1.metcheck.com/ENGINE/v9_0/json.asp?lat=52.6&lon=-2&lid=60883&Fc=No"
    Dim uri As New Uri(uriString)

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.Method = "GET"

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()


    Dim read As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim raw As String = read.ReadToEnd

    Dim dict As Metdata
    dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Metdata)(raw)


End Sub

Partial Public Class Metdata
    Public Property myDictionary As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
End Class
Public Class Forecast

        <JsonProperty("temperature")>
        Public Property Temperature As String

        <JsonProperty("dewpoint")>
        Public Property Dewpoint As String

        <JsonProperty("rain")>
        Public Property Rain As String

        <JsonProperty("freezinglevel")>
        Public Property Freezinglevel As String

        <JsonProperty("uvIndex")>
        Public Property UvIndex As String

        <JsonProperty("totalcloud")>
        Public Property Totalcloud As String

        <JsonProperty("lowcloud")>
        Public Property Lowcloud As String

        <JsonProperty("medcloud")>
        Public Property Medcloud As String

        <JsonProperty("highcloud")>
        Public Property Highcloud As String

        <JsonProperty("humidity")>
        Public Property Humidity As String

        <JsonProperty("windspeed")>
        Public Property Windspeed As String

        <JsonProperty("meansealevelpressure")>
        Public Property Meansealevelpressure As String

        <JsonProperty("windgustspeed")>
        Public Property Windgustspeed As String

        <JsonProperty("winddirection")>
        Public Property Winddirection As String

        <JsonProperty("windletter")>
        Public Property Windletter As String

        <JsonProperty("icon")>
        Public Property Icon As String

        <JsonProperty("iconName")>
        Public Property IconName As String

        <JsonProperty("chanceofrain")>
        Public Property Chanceofrain As String

        <JsonProperty("chanceofsnow")>
        Public Property Chanceofsnow As String

        <JsonProperty("dayOfWeek")>
        Public Property DayOfWeek As String

        <JsonProperty("weekday")>
        Public Property Weekday As String

        <JsonProperty("sunrise")>
        Public Property Sunrise As String

        <JsonProperty("sunset")>
        Public Property Sunset As String

        <JsonProperty("dayOrNight")>
        Public Property DayOrNight As String

        <JsonProperty("utcTime")>
        Public Property UtcTime As DateTime
    End Class

Public Class ForecastLocation

    <JsonProperty("forecast")>
    Public Property Forecast As Forecast()

    <JsonProperty("continent")>
    Public Property Continent As String

    <JsonProperty("country")>
    Public Property Country As String

    <JsonProperty("location")>
    Public Property Location As String

    <JsonProperty("latitude")>
    Public Property Latitude As Double

    <JsonProperty("longitude")>
    Public Property Longitude As Double

    <JsonProperty("timezone")>
    Public Property Timezone As Integer
End Class

Public Class MetcheckData

    <JsonProperty("forecastLocation")>
    Public Property ForecastLocation As ForecastLocation
End Class

Public Class Metdata

    <JsonProperty("metcheckData")>
    Public Property MetcheckData As MetcheckData

    <JsonProperty("feedCreation")>
    Public Property FeedCreation As DateTime

    <JsonProperty("feedCreator")>
    Public Property FeedCreator As String

    <JsonProperty("feedModel")>
    Public Property FeedModel As String

    <JsonProperty("feedModelRun")>
    Public Property FeedModelRun As String

    <JsonProperty("feedModelRunInitialTime")>
    Public Property FeedModelRunInitialTime As DateTime

    <JsonProperty("feedResolution")>
    Public Property FeedResolution As String
End Class
```

dict.Metcheckdata.Forecastlocation.Forecast will contain your 155 records.

Comment: the top to lines work, however Forecast does not have any properties under it:
    TextBox1.Text &= dict.FeedCreator.ToString & vbCrLf
    TextBox1.Text &= dict.MetcheckData.ForecastLocation.Latitude.ToString & vbCrLf
    TextBox1.Text &= dict.MetcheckData.ForecastLocation.Forecast.Rain.ToString & vbCrLf
The last line produces:
Error BC30456 'Rain' is not a member of 'Weather.Forecast()'.

Comment: It does definitely contain all your data. Please put a breakpoint and inspect the data structure of dict.